# Как передать что-то в конструктор в middleware

Tags: php, laravel

Есть middleware в конструктор которого хочу передать определенный параметр, что бы явно внедрять зависимость и не делать что-то типо того:

```
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->default_ref = config('TEST_CONFIG', 'http://test');
    }
```

а выполнить что-то типо того

```
public function __construct($default_ref)
{
    $this->default_ref = $default_ref;
}
```

Буду благодарен за подсказку как я это могу сделать

Comment: С учетом специфики работы middleware в Laravel, не думаю, что так можно делать...

Comment: А где и как будет вызываться этот конструктор? Проще доставать переменные в процессе обработки данных в handle, чем пытаться натянуть сами знаете кого на глобус; тем паче что данные в конфиге будут статично доступны (прекомпилированы) в процессе исполнения.

Answer (score 0):

Как бы это правильно пояснить...
При вызове посредников (middleware) выполняется метод handle (если его не переопределять). Посредники явно не создаются, поэтому конструктор по сути не задействуется. Но в него можно включать зависимости и они заинжектятся (это чтобы в handle не писать `new SomeClass()`)

А теперь о возможности передачи параметров. Из документации. Их можно передать в метод hadle. Делается это через `:` и разделяются параметры запятыми

```
Route::put('/post/{id}', function ($id) {
    //
})->middleware('role:editor');
```

и в самом посреднике

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $role)
{
    if (! $request->user()->hasRole($role)) {
        // Redirect...
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Если смотреть на Ваш вопрос, то вы можете передать параметр (главное, чтобы это была строка, которая не содержит запятых)

```
Route::put('/post/{id}', function ($id) {
    //
})->middleware('redirect:' . $default_ref);
```